# Pass run time variable from python to ipython notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, global-variables, pytest

I am modifying some of the existing pytests for my python project and I have come across this one scenario where I need to pass tmp_path from my pytest to notebook file.

```
@yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session_tmp_path():
    with TemporaryDirectory(suffix=__name__) as tmp_dir:
        yield Path(tmp_dir)
```

This is a fixture which is used in my pytest and all the test use this path for storing all the artifacts.

```
def test_catch_up(session_tmp_path, dask_client, heuristics_logs, op_name, versions):
    report_operation = CATALOG_LAYER_OPS[op_name]
    report_operation(start_date=date(2019, 10, 1), end_date=date(2019, 10, 1), client=dask_client,
                     batch_size=10, limit=10, catalog_id='CATALOG_ID',
                     layer_id='eso-speed-LAYER_ID', versions=versions,
                    **input_directory=str(session_tmp_path)**,
                      monitor_directory=heuristics_logs,
                     output_directory=str(session_tmp_path), base_map_dvn="123",
                     force=False, num_workers=1, spark_scheduler=None, countries=None)
```

I want this temp path(passed as input_directory to python methods) to be passed to one of my notebook because I eventually want artifacts which are created using that notebook to also fall into same temp location.
All the artifacts which are created using my python code are properly created in temp location but the artifacts created because of notebook is created at different location because I am unable to pass this temp location to notebook.

I have tried various options such as using getter setter, using global variables and importing those in notebook but when notebook is executed it always picks the default value of variable and not the newly assigned one within method block.

For eg-

```
INPUT_DIRECT = 'default'

def run_report(catalog_id: str, layer_id: str, version: int,
                       input_directory, output_directory, force=False, **kwargs):
    report = Report.from_tokens((catalog_id, layer_id, version))
    if not force and report.dataset_exists(output_directory):
        logger.info("Dataset exists, skipping")
    else:
        global INPUT_DIRECT
        INPUT_DIRECT = input_directory
        dataset = get_final_dataset(CatalogLayer(catalog_id, layer_id, version), input_directory)

def getInputPath(param=None):
    if param==None:
        param = INPUT_DIRECT
    else:
        param = None
    return param
```

And then calling this getInputPath from Notebook.

```
from main_test.reportForStudent import getInputPath
finalPath = getInputPath(None)
```

finalPath returns default and not the expected path.

Is there any simpler way through which this can be done ?